# If video has prop autoplay don't pause when out of viewport

Tags: jquery, video, viewport, autoplay, pause

I am using isinViewport from https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport to play/pause videos when in/out of view. But sometimes I don't want them to autoplay (for videos that are not muted and with controls).

Hence I am checking for if is in viewport & with property autoplay

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    
    /* activate pause for lightbulb video if scrolled out of viewport */
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('video').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":in-viewport()") && $(this).prop('autoplay')) {
                $(this)[0].play();
            } else {
                $(this)[0].pause();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now. This works great. But, my videos that are set to autoplay stop once you scroll a bit and this is not desirable behaviour. Is there a way to sort of say: else, and with prop autoplay, do nothing?

Perhaps I need two different if statements. If with prop autoplay do nothing? else if play, and else pause?

All help in the right direction appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include an attribute selector in the `video` selector to exclude the videos which have `autoplay` set on them when the page loads from the scroll update logic.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  "use strict";
  let $videos = $('video:not([autoplay])');

  /* activate pause for lightbulb video if scrolled out of viewport */
  $(window).on('scroll', () => {
    $videos.each(function() {
      $(this).is(":in-viewport()") ? this.play() : this.pause();
    });
  });
});
```

Note that I amended the logic slightly so that you avoid creating jQuery objects within the `scroll` event handler, which can be a massive performance drain, and also redundant in cases where `$(this)[0]` can be replaced with just `this`.

Comment: I had to alter the first bit to listen to document.ready but otherwise yes, this did the trick! Thank you! Another small problem occurred after this though. Once a video with autoplayed is played and then manually paused... it does not stay paused when scrolling occurs, but instead plays again on scroll. Might there be a simple solution to this?

Comment: The first line is still a document.ready handler, but I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: Regarding the pause/play issue, I'd suggest putting a class on the elements which have been interacted with by the user so that you can filter them out from this logic so that their state is kept and not changed on scroll.

Comment: Sort of like an addclassname after user interacts with controls yes? I will play around with it. And then include that class name in the arguments, something like let $videos = $('video:not([autoplay])') || $('.classname'); ? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Works great in safari but didn't work in chrome I noticed just now. Puh.

Comment: Try `$videos.filter(':not(.classname)').each(...`